# What's wrong with MovingMap + Apply[Rule] etc.?

Tags: functions, bugs

I don't why this happens, I don't know if those two examples are related.

I don't have time to investigate, but maybe someone can solve this?

```
MovingMap[Apply[RandomReal], Range[5], 1]
```

> ```
> MovingMap[Apply[RandomReal], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 1]
> ```
>
> TemporalData::dmnsns: The dimensionality implied by the states in 
>       {{{0.8754,0.581},{1.10292,<<19>>,1.3597},{<<1>>},{1.19292,1.14424,0.278258,3.10511,1.18676}}} 
>       is mixed. A single-state dimensionality is expected. >>

and:

```
MovingMap[Apply[Rule], Range[5], 1]
```

> ```
> MovingMap[Apply[Rule], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 1]
> ```

*I don't need workarounds since they are basic.*

Win7, V10.2, V10.3

Comment: If someone is interested, please send a bug report, something is wrong with my license or with me but I'm not getting anything back from them lately.

Comment: V.10.0.0.0 -- First example: Can't repro; second -- *Rule::argr: Rule called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.*

Comment: I confirm, 10.3 on Linux. Something wrong in the output stage of `MovingMap`. I see echo from `Apply[Rule]@*Echo` and the correct output from `List@*Apply[Rule]`.

Comment: `PrintDefinitions` and other techniques reveal that this is an issue of ``TemporalData`Utilities`TDRollingMap``

Comment: Also note that with a fresh kernel, `Quiet[MovingMap[Apply[RandomReal], Range[5], 1]]` still issues a message, which I guess is a bug of `Quiet`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a limitation in `TemporalData` that `MovingMap` was designed to work with. Note that `TimeSeries` and `EventSeries` are really just special cases. I don't know if it is a necessary limitation but a decision was made at the time they were created that the dimensionality of the data values need to be consistent.

Now whether this restriction should be relaxed and whether it should operate differently on lists is certainly a valid question. I also think it should be a little smarter about what message it issues and the documentation should be more clear about this limitation.

All that said, since it was a deliberate design decision, I don't think WRI will consider this a bug in the functionality but a bad message and incomplete documentation.

**EDIT**

Now when it comes to why `Rule` behaves differently. Under the hood everything gets packaged up in `TemporalData` and is checked for consistency using `TemporalData`'s internal validation functions. But `TemporalData` seems to have special handling for a list of `Rule`, presumably allowing for a specification `{time1 -> value1, time2 -> value2, ...}`. An undocumented feature?  In any case, this is surprising and shouldn't occur when `MovingMap` is given a list since the user has no reason to expect that this has anything to do with `TemporalData`.

```
In[87]:= TemporalData[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6, 7 -> 8}]["Path"]

Out[87]= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}

In[88]:= TemporalData[{h[1, 2], h[3, 4], h[5, 6], h[7, 8]}]["Path"]

Out[88]= {{0, h[1, 2]}, {1, h[3, 4]}, {2, h[5, 6]}, {3, h[7, 8]}}
```